# How to pull entries with 'Shared' Foreign Keys from a Single Table

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say that I have a table called Color_Size_Rel that looks like this

```
 Color_Size_ID           Color                Size
        1                Blue                  L 
        2                Blue                  M
        3                Green                 L
        4                Purple                L
        5                Pink                  XL
        6                White                 S
        7                Blue                  L
```

What would be the query to pull the colors / the number of colors with the same Size? The expected result set is below:

```
Blue
Green
Purple
```

I've tried the following to no avail (I'm really stuck and have no idea how this would be done):

```
     select color
       from color_size_rel
      where size = size;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't a `WHERE` clause do what you want?

Comment: What is the output you're expecting to receive from your query? Please edit your question to add the expected output.

Comment: Sounds like you need a simple group like `SELECT Color, Size, COUNT(*) FROM color_size_rel GROUP BY Color, Size`. But as @Boneist said, the expected output would *really* help.

Comment: Sorry folks, I thought I added it in there. Just added the expected result set

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `exists` subquery to make it.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.color
FROM Color_Size_Rel t1
WHERE exists (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Color_Size_Rel tt
    WHERE t1.Size = tt.Size
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c255d/2/0)**:

```
|  color |
|--------|
|   Blue |
|  Green |
| Purple |
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
WITH color_size_rel AS (SELECT 1 color_size_id, 'Blue' color, 'L' "SIZE" FROM dual UNION ALL
                        SELECT 2 color_size_id, 'Blue' color, 'M' "SIZE" FROM dual UNION ALL
                        SELECT 3 color_size_id, 'Green' color, 'L' "SIZE" FROM dual UNION ALL
                        SELECT 4 color_size_id, 'Purple' color, 'L' "SIZE" FROM dual UNION ALL
                        SELECT 5 color_size_id, 'Pink' color, 'XL' "SIZE" FROM dual UNION ALL
                        SELECT 6 color_size_id, 'White' color, 'S' "SIZE" FROM dual UNION ALL
                        SELECT 6 color_size_id, 'Orange' color, 'S' "SIZE" FROM dual UNION ALL
                        SELECT 7 color_size_id, 'Blue' color, 'L' "SIZE" FROM dual)
SELECT "SIZE", color
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT "SIZE",
                        color,
                        COUNT(DISTINCT color) OVER (PARTITION BY "SIZE") cnt
        FROM   color_size_rel)
WHERE  cnt > 1
ORDER BY "SIZE", color;

SIZE COLOR
---- ------
L    Blue
L    Green
L    Purple
S    Orange
S    White
```

(I added an extra colour in size "S" to demonstrate the output when there are multiple sizes with more than one colour.)

This finds the count of distinct colours per size, and then distincts the result set, so that if there are duplicate colours in each size, only one is reported. Finally, we filter the results to show those sizes which have a count that is greater than 1.

N.B. Please don't use `size` as a column name - it's a reserved word, hence why I had to use double-quotes every time I referenced it.

Answer (score 0):

Select distinct colour from colour_size_rel where size=size

Comment: That would return colours for all sizes, not just those sizes which have more than one colour associated with them.